# In nightwatch framework difference nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js vs nightwatch.conf.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

1. What is the difference between **nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js and
   nightwatch.conf.js** in nightwatch framework.
2. And what is basic requirement for setup nightwatch framework with
   node js and selenium

Comment: Does my answer below makes sense for you?

Comment: yes, Thank You  brother

Comment: so can you mark it my answer as "answered"?

Comment: HOw to marked as "answered"

Comment: You simply need to mark my answer as correct (the green check image) like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no differences between `nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js` and `nightwatch.conf.js`.

You have just to know 5 things:

- 1. You can name your config file as you want (*nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js*, *nightwatch.json*, *nightwatch.conf.js* or *anything.json* or *anything.js*)
- 2. You can have **more than 1 config file** per project.
- 3. When you put your Nightwatch configuration in a file named `nightwatch.json` or `nightwatch.conf.js` you don't need to say which configuration file should be used since

     > A **nightwatch.conf.js** file or a **nightwatch.json** file will also be loaded by default, if found.

     Just keep in mind that:

     > The **nightwatch.conf.js** always takes precedence over
     >   **nightwatch.json** if both are present.

     In this case, you can launch your tests like this:

     `$> nightwatch`
- 4. When you put your Nightwatch configuration in an other file, you **must** tell Nightwatch where are the configurations to use. In this case you need to write your tests like this (for example in Node.js):

     `module.exports = (function(settings) {
     //....
     })(require('path/to.your/config/file'));`

     or

     `var config = require('path/to.your/config/file');
     module.exports = {
     //....
     };`

     In this case, you need to specify which configuration file to take when launching tests:

     `$> nightwatch --config path/to.your/config/file`
- 5. Since naming your config file **nightwatch.conf.js** or **nightwatch.json** doesn't change anything to Nightwatch, is there a reason to choose one and not the other?

     Answer: Yes!

     Why?: Sometimes you need to write a *JavaScript* code in your configuration file. In this case your file should be a *.js* file and not a *.json* file.

     Example of use? When you have many environments to test, maybe you don't want to update many lines to change the same information. So you write a *nightwatch.conf.js* (The objective is to just change one line when you want to deactivate *video* instead of going to each environment in a *.json* file and make changes):

```
    nightwatch_config = {
      src_folders : [ "a/file/to/test" ],
      selenium : {/*...*/},
      common_capabilities: {/*...*/},
      test_settings: {
      default: {},
      chrome: {desiredCapabilities: {browser: "chrome"}},
      firefox: {desiredCapabilities: {browser: "firefox"}},
      safari: {desiredCapabilities: {browser: "safari"}},
      ie: {desiredCapabilities: {browser: "internet explorer"}}
    }
    };
    for(var i in nightwatch_config.test_settings){
      var config = nightwatch_config.test_settings[i];
      for(var j in nightwatch_config.common_capabilities){
        config['desiredCapabilities'][j][browserstack.video] = true;
      }
    }
    module.exports = nightwatch_config;
```